# Sri Rudram modern western scholarly translation

Tags: translation

This is a request for a modern translation of Sri Rudram, preferably by a western Sanskrit scholar who does not belong to any Hindu tradition. Translations available online have a lot of assumptions inbuilt in them. I want to obtain a scholarly translation which makes as few assumptions as possible. At the same time, I do not want 19th century obscure translations. A modern western scholarly translation would be ideal. Please let me know if such a translation is available.

Comment: You can check MaxMuller's works to see if he has translated Sri Rudram. I don't recall top off my head. I do remember his works involving Upanisads, and I don't remember if he translated the karma khanda parts of the Yajur Veda.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes for the "western" part of the question. As for "modern" part of the question I am not sure, but any thing you find may be secondary work.

Secondly the translations available are, for the entire Yajur Veda as opposed to just the Rudram part. So you can navigate to the specific chapters.

For the Vajasaneyi Rudram (i.e. the Rudram which is the 16th chapter of the Shukla Yajur Veda), see The book published by The Parimal Pulication, which is actually adapted from the translation by Ralph T H Griffith. Here are the links:

http://www.parimalpublication.com/index.php?route=product/product&filter_name=Yajur&product_id=30

The Rudram in the Krishna Yajur Veda is also available as part of the complete translation of Yajur Veda provided by J. Muir, in the multi-volume works called "Original Sanskrit Texts". Check the volume 4 here at the following link. Go to page 322 for the commentary on Shatarudriya.  Note the page number is the actual number printed on the page of the book that was converted into the PDF document. So as you scroll, look for the number printed on the page, as opposed to the number shown in the PDF software frame (like Adobe reader or whatever you use).

https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.217261

Another translation of the Shukla Yajur Veda Rudram is available by Prof A. Weber, which I am not sure if available on the Internet. You can search to see if it is.

Finally as I mentioned in my comment, Max Muller did comment on it. Here is the link for the translation by Max Muller, which again, is the Shukla Yajur Veda part

https://en.wikisource.org/w/index.php?title=File%3ASacred_Books_of_the_East_-_Volume_43.djvu&page=180

Note the 180 at the end of the URL. When you go to that page, the content is in the 150th page of the actual PDF "document", but if you navigate using the button on the right, you need to go to 180 of the "file" / "archive"

All Max Muller's works are available in wikisource: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Sacred_Books_of_the_East